# Approximating non-linear function with NN using Theano

Tags: python, neural-network, theano

I have designed a neural network using Theano, to approximate mathematical multiple functions. But I, haven't been able to approximate non-linear functions such as: 2x/x+3, etc. But the network performs well on linear functions.

I am using 1 hidden layer, with 2 neurons. I have tried increasing neurons in the hidden layer. But, that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

**NOTE:** the code doesn't have any errors. It also tries to minimize cost, but the predictions it's making are not what are expected (maybe it's learning some meaningless/unwanted pattern).

The (**UPDATED-UPDATED**) code I am using is:

```
x = T.dscalar()
y = T.dscalar()

inputs = np.random.randint(1,6,size=(500))
outputs = (inputs * 2.0) / (inputs + 3.0)

def layer(x, w):
    b = np.array([1], dtype=theano.config.floatX)
    x = b * x    # doing to be able to concatenate b and x
    x = T.concatenate([x, b])
    return nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(w.T, x))

def grad_desc(cost, theta):
    alpha = 0.01
    return theta - (alpha * (T.grad(cost, wrt=theta)))

theta1 = theano.shared(np.array(np.random.rand(2,6), dtype=theano.config.floatX))
theta2 = theano.shared(np.array(np.random.rand(7,1), dtype=theano.config.floatX))

h1 = layer(x, theta1)
h2 = layer(h1, theta2)
out = T.nnet.softmax(h2)
fc = T.mean(T.sqr(out - y))

back_prop = theano.function(inputs=[x,y], outputs=[fc], updates=[
                (theta1, grad_desc(fc, theta1)),
                (theta2, grad_desc(fc, theta2))
            ])
feed_forward = theano.function(inputs=[x], outputs=[out])

cur_cost = 0
for i in range(100):
    for x, y in zip(inputs, outputs):
        cur_cost = back_prop(x, y)
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print "Epoch ", i/10, " : ", cur_cost
```

Costs respective to Epochs:

```
Epoch  0  :  [array(0.0625)]
Epoch  1  :  [array(0.0625)]
Epoch  2  :  [array(0.0625)]
Epoch  3  :  [array(0.0625)]
Epoch  4  :  [array(0.0625)]
Epoch  5  :  [array(0.0625)]
Epoch  6  :  [array(0.0625)]
Epoch  7  :  [array(0.0625)]
Epoch  8  :  [array(0.0625)]
Epoch  9  :  [array(0.0625)]
```

Testing:

```
test_values = np.random.randint(1,100, size=(1,6))
for i in test_values[0]:
    print "Result : ", feed_forward(i), "Actual : ", (2.0*i)/(i+3.0)
```

Testing results:

```
Result :  [array([[ 1.]])] Actual :  1.90909090909
Result :  [array([[ 1.]])] Actual :  1.82857142857
Result :  [array([[ 1.]])] Actual :  1.66666666667
Result :  [array([[ 1.]])] Actual :  1.93023255814
Result :  [array([[ 1.]])] Actual :  1.7
Result :  [array([[ 1.]])] Actual :  1.85714285714
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not a neural network... at least not in the meaningfull sense - it is just a linear model. There is no point in having a hidden layer, when you do not have any nonlinear activation function, as everything you can model is just a linear function of your input. Add nonlinearities, add their respective gradients, and then you will be able to model nonlinear functions.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I used Sigmoid non-linearity (have updated the code). But even then it's not producing expected results. Can you kindly point out, where am I doing mistake.

Comment: Next thing is lack of learnable bias, you fixed ot to be one(very weird idea). And why you sum in the out variable?

Comment: as the output, will be a sum of outputs of all 6 neurons in the hidden layer, so we need to sum them up

Comment: No, it is not supposed to be sum, it is supposed to be a linear layer, thus trainable weighted sum. This code seems to have lots of errors, thus fixing all of them might be problematic in So scope

Comment: I have done changes you suggested - added learnable biases, added softmax at output layer. And tried to remove ambiguities. But, I still cannot figure out a way. Can you have a look at it, and identify if am doing it wrong?

Comment: You are not supposed to use softmax for reggression. You should really go through basic course of NN, maybe haykins book will help? Neural networks and learning machines

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion.